# Making a Master Employee Workbook so I can link other workbooks to it and edit the master workbook to change three other workbooks at one time.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to make a master employee list with sonority numbers listed in excel and then link that workbook to other excel workbooks that my workers can then sort and rearrange in their workbooks but when I edit the master workbook it will update their workbooks. I see a lot of information on gathering information from separate worksheets into one but none about how to make one and have it control others. 
Thank you in advance for any help. 
Oma K

Comment: You'll want to "push" the updates out to the other workbooks. This works almost exactly the same way as "pulling" data, but the destination wb is the wb you're opening